# Highcharts undefined value

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo $chartURL; ?>", function (data) {

      var seriesData = [];

      // split the data set into crypto and volume
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      seriesData.push({
          x: data[i].time,
          y: data[i].open,
          high: data[i].high
      });
    }

    console.log(seriesData);
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<br/>' +
                    'Open: <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>' +
                    'High: <b>' + this.point.high + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
              type: 'line',
              name: 'USD',
              data: seriesData,
              turboThreshold: 0
              }]
    });
});
```

In for loop I have defined value `high` and I pass the variable in `tooltip`, but script return error:

> Cannot read property 'high' of undefined

When I change `tooltip` to this:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) +'</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                s += '<br/>High: ' + seriesData[i].high + '<br/>Price: ' + point.y;
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

the script does not return any error but the value of `high` is still the same, it does not change.

I try use:
`this.point.high, point.high, this.data.high, this.seriesData[i].high` ... still I have error `undefined`

All values are taken from JSON:

```
[{"time":1347321600000,"open":11.17,"high":11.35,"low":10.88,"close":11.33,"volumeto":721708.44},{"time":1347408000000,"open":11.33,"high":11.39,"low":10.78,"close":11.36,"volumeto":657004.1},{"time":1347494400000,"open":11.36,"high":11.4,"low":11.22,"close":11.4,"volumeto":233401.71},{"time":1347580800000,"open":11.4,"high":11.8,"low":11.32,"close":11.67,"volumeto":500768.38},{"time":1347667200000,"open":11.67,"high":11.79,"low":11.6,"close":11.75,"volumeto":190511.93},{"time":1347753600000,"open":11.75,"high":11.99,"low":11.72,"close":11.87,"volumeto":359833.88}...]
```

Comment: Where does the `point` come from? -> `this.high`

Comment: @Andreas I do not know if that's what you mean, but all values are taken from JSON, in variable `$chartURL`, I added to my post JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `high` key is inside `this.points[0].point` object, so your tooltip code will be:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
        console.log(this.points);
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', new Date(this.x)) + '<br/>' +
                'Open: <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>' +
                'High: <b>' + this.points[0].point.high + '</b>';
        }
    },
```

Check the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4LL4v55o/7/)

Comment: thanks, for your answer, but I have second problem, I can get only 560 records from JSON and script work correctly, but when I get 561 record value `high` is undefined. I don't know why ...?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, when the JSON records are 561 you get the error? Or when the amounts of records are 560 and when you hit the 561 `high` is undefined?